# How do I check if a Variant is a TDateTime?

Tags: delphi, variant, tdatetime

I have an object, that has one value, but that value can either be an `integer`, `string`, `boolean` or `TDateTime`.  So, it is a `Variant`.

I use `VarType()` to check its type, but since `VarType()` has no 'varDate' or 'varDateTime', I am using 'varDouble', because as far as I can gather, a `TDateTime` is a `double`.

But that returns false.  I also cannot use `is` to check if the `Variant` is `TDateTime`.  Is there a way, or should I make some sort of type variable that determines which type the value is and use that to check it?

Comment: Anyway, you don't need to make your own function to check a variant type. There's already the [`VarIsType`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Variants.VarIsType) function to do so.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your assumptions are incorrect; there is in fact a `varDate`.

Comment: @Svip: Things like that happen to me too sometimes!